# vsftpd ubuntu 13.10 login incorrect

Tags: server, login, vsftpd

I can't login to my vsftpd server - I am getting error `530 Login incorrect.` How to fix it?

**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

# I tried both...
#pam_service_name=ftp
pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

**/etc/pam.d/vsftpd**

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required    pam_shells.so
```

**/etc/ftpusers**

```
# /etc/ftpusers: list of users disallowed FTP access. See ftpusers(5).

# commented 'root' for tests. can't login either
#root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
nobody
```

**/etc/shells**

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
```

**/var/log/vsftpd.log**

```
...
Wed Apr  9 16:49:07 2014 [pid 9838] CONNECT: Client "127.0.0.1"
Wed Apr  9 16:49:09 2014 [pid 9837] [my-username] FAIL LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1"
```

**$ groups**

```
my-username adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev fuse lpadmin sambashare ftp
```

**$ id my-username**

```
uid=1000(my-username) gid=1000(my-username) groups=4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),104(fuse),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),129(ftp),1000(my-username)
```

I tried to change `pam_service_name`, added `seccomp_sandbox=NO`, I reinstalled vsftpd, I tried dpkg-reconfingure (I restarted vsftpd service after every config change). Still no success...

Obviously user `my-username` exists, and it's in `ftp` group as above.

How to make vsftpd works?

I haven't use vsftpd for some time and it stopped working after some update. I am using xubuntu 13.10

**Edit:** just tried same settings on different computer (fresh xubuntu install) and it works OK. what am I missing?

Currently I am just using pure-ftp...

Comment: Any reason you are using traditional ftp over sftp? Not a constructive comment. Just curious really.

Comment: @PeteyT it's complicated :]

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: http://senthilthoppur.blogspot.com/2012/08/vsftpd-530-permission-denied-root.html

You can try adding "userlist_deny=" in the "/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf" file.

If  "userlist_deny=NO", it will only allow users in the file "/etc/vsftpd/user_list".

You can also refer to : http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=112812

Comment: didn't work. i think it's not about permissions, it's like vsftpd have no users list?